# How to avoid TagManager "IllegalStateException: Results have already been set"

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-tag-manager

I have recently introduced Google TagManager into my Android app in order to push changes to app config without needing to redeploy the app.

But I am getting instances of:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Results have already been set
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.p.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ed.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ed.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ed$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ed$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.cj.c(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ck.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

They occur across a variety of devices from Android 4.4 to 5.0.1

As you can see there is no element of my app in the stacktrace, and I am really at a loss and to what I can do (other than remove TagManager) to avoid or mitigate the error.

I have found one reference to the same error message associated with GooglePlus login so I am thinking it might be to do with the Google Play Services library.

Anyone else seen it?
Any ideas?

Have raised issue with Play-Games project:
  https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=209

Comment: Have you tried downloading TagManager SDK & decompile everything + grep a "Results have been already set"? That will explain exactly when this error is thrown, it'll lead you eventually to a solution.

Comment: What Google Play Services version are you using? Have you seen the latest docs, updated Dec 18th? https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

Comment: @JaredBurrows 6.1.71 and yes I have thanks.

Comment: I just got a very similar stacktrace, which seems to be tagmanager related I'm using play-services 6.5.87. My user wrote as comment that he did not use the device for about 10 hours and the last usage of my app was two days ago. Maybe something about the lifecycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an internal bug due to a race condition within TagManager and should be fixed in Google Play Services 6.7 (February 17, 2015).

See https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tag-manager/NOlng117_2g/w46OkQS5Gm8J
and also https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/changelog

In the mean time you can work around it by:

```
private static class MyHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

    MyHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler) {
        this.defaultHandler = defaultHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        String classpath = null;
        if (ex != null && ex.getStackTrace().length > 0) {
            classpath = ex.getStackTrace()[0].toString();
        }
        if (classpath != null && 
            ex.getMessage().contains("Results have already been set") && 
            classpath.contains("com.google.android.gms.tagmanager") ) {
            // ignore
         } else {
           // run your default handler
           defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
       }
    }
};

// Application#onCreate
public void onCreate() {
    // for catching app global unhandled exceptions
    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyHandler(defaultHandler));
}
```

Comment: The uncaughtException is never called. Although, I added the code exactly the way you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

According to this link, Google has fixed this issue in newer versions:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/changelog

Comment: It is better also to add that the "fix" would be to upgrade to Google Play Services 6.7